# Is it possible to loop through a text file with camel to create routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Pretty new to Camel myself. 
Right now I am routing a file from an FTP into HDFS. That text file contains a list of other files that must be routed from that FTP to HDFS. This text file is updated daily with new files to be moved.
I am using a bean to parse the text file into a list and clean it up just so it has the exact file paths. Now my question is, can I create a loop to go through this list and create a new route for each file within? P.S not very good with java either, so don't laugh too much.

```
public class DailyDownloader {
public List<String> splitDaily(String body) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Printing Download List");


    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(body));
    String line=null;
    bufReader.readLine();
    List<String> dailyFilesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while( (line=bufReader.readLine()) != null )
    {
        String fileName = line.split("\\|", 2)[0];

        dailyFilesList.add(fileName);

    }
    System.out.println(dailyFilesList);
    return dailyFilesList;

}
```

The above list returns something like:
/camelfiles/file1

/camelfiles/abc/file123.txt

/maven/settings.xml

etc..

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any control over the remote FTP server? What you are trying to do can be done, I just don't know how scalable it is. In other words, I have to imagine there is an upper limit to how many routes you can add to a Camel Context.

Comment: The FTP is actually vendor controlled. I dont see scalability being too much of an issue. Its usually under 20 files. @rmlan

Comment: Right, but this is supposed to happen daily. Is this a long-running camel process? Or is this something that runs once daily?

Comment: It should run once every morning @rmlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably solve it like this:

1. One route to pick up the file and parse it.
2. For every filename send the file path to another route. You can do this via some event bus like ActiveMQ or internally via direct
3. This route picks up the file from the FTP site and saves it somewhere.

There is no need to start a new route for file. You just need to divide the problem into separate components.